# How can I have my nextjs app and my strapi CMS have the same domain and subdomain?

Tags: heroku, next.js, strapi

I have 2 apps on my heroku, one for my nextjs page and another for my strapi headless CMS. Right now I have a subdomain for strapi, and the root domain for nextjs.
I use heroku, my current situation is subdomain.example.com/admin for strapi and example.com for nextjs.

What I wanted was example.com for nextjs and example.com/admin for strapi.

Thanks